# keeping ssh session alive vs reconnecting

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, ssh, paramiko

I'm developing in python using paramiko and
I was wondering, performance wise, is it better to create a single (long) ssh connection and keep it open during the scope of the code, Or working in 'bursts' and creating and closing new connections after each ssh command.

my code:

```
connection.connect(...)
send ssh command
# do something else for 5 minutes
send another ssh command
# do something else for another 5 minutes
send another ssh command
connection.close()
```

Moreover, the code should open many (~50) connections simultaneously to different servers from the machine i run the code from.
Considering the amount of open ssh sessions is it better to create long connections, or cut the connection after each ssh command?

Answer (score 0):

> performance wise, is it better to create a single (long) ssh connection and keep it open during the scope of the code, Or working in 'bursts' and creating and closing new connections after each ssh command.

Performance-wise, it is definitely better to keep one connection open. Opening an SSH connection is CPU-intensive process.

> Considering the amount of open ssh sessions is it better to create long connections, or cut the connection after each ssh command?

Better for what? For performance, the answer is still the same.

Comment: i'll clarify, "better" as in "is it right in this situation to hold 50 open connections simultaneously" in this given case. opening and closing connections may be CPU-intensive, but holding ~50 open connections shouldn't be that easy either.

Comment: *"but holding ~50 open connections shouldn't be that easy either"* -- Why? It would consume some memory, but other then that, 50 connections is not that much.